# Reaction CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST

Tags: javascript, node.js, reaction-commerce

I´m trying to run reaction, but I´ve got this error:

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST allocation failed - Javascript heap out of memory.

I´ve been following this guide for installation
https://docs.reactioncommerce.com/docs/next/installation-windows

and I´m on step, run reaction:

```
# start Reaction
reaction
# or
reaction run
```

But I got this error

```
    C:\Users\rg\Documents\myReaction\reaction>reaction
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Setting up plugin imports...

Setting up style imports...

Provisioning assets...

[[[[[ C:\Users\rg\Documents\myReaction\reaction ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
app/client/plugins.less: warn: There are some @import rules those are not taking effect as they are required to be in the beginning of the file.
app/client/plugins.less: warn: There are some @import rules those are not taking effect as they are required to be in the beginning of the file.
   Building for os.windows.x86_64            \
<--- Last few GCs --->

[4340:000001E838675AB0]   510760 ms: Mark-sweep 1313.1 (1441.7) -> 1313.1 (1441.7) MB, 1340.6 / 0.2 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[4340:000001E838675AB0]   512026 ms: Mark-sweep 1313.1 (1441.7) -> 1313.1 (1425.2) MB, 1265.4 / 0.3 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[4340:000001E838675AB0]   513465 ms: Mark-sweep 1313.1 (1425.2) -> 1313.1 (1425.2) MB, 1439.4 / 0.2 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000003BA0CF25879 <JSObject>
    0: builtin exit frame: stringify(this=000003BA0CF090A9 <Object map = 0000016865602BA1>,00000321ED7822D1 <undefined>,00000321ED7822D1 <undefined>,00000015838125E1 <JSArray[2]>)

    1: arguments adaptor frame: 1->3
    2: _linkJS [C:\Users\rg\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.8.0-rc.14\mt-os.windows.x86_64\tools\isobuild\compiler-plugin.js:~1569] [pc=000003E280B1B649](thi...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node_module_register
 2: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawOneByteString
 5: v8::internal::Smi::SmiPrint
 6: v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts
 7: v8::internal::wasm::LocalDeclEncoder::Size
 8: v8::internal::wasm::LocalDeclEncoder::Size
```

I don´t know how to increase the memory and if it must be done in for node or meteor.

Thanks.

Comment: I also tried: npm install; meteor npm install --save-deep-equal; meteor npm install --save bcrypt; npm install core-js; and after I tried to run with TOOL_NODE_FLAGS="-max_old_space_size=1024" reaction

Comment: I too got this error!